# Air Datepicker: получить диапазон даты в строке URL

Tags: jquery, datepicker

[jQuery календарь Air Datepicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html).
В [коде](https://codepen.io/iddqdoom/pen/rgaVoL) предлагаю способ получения диапазона даты в строке URL. Можете предложить решение рациональней?
Нужно получить get-параметром дату. При выборе даты страница обновляется и с сервера приходят отфильтрованные данные. Не предлагайте, пожалуйста, POST ajax'ом.

```
<form id="js-datepicker-form" onsubmit="alert('submit!');return false">
  <label class="datepicker-here js-datepicker" for="date">
  <input type="hidden" id="date" name="date">
</form>

<script>
    var myDatepicker = $('.js-datepicker').datepicker({
        range: true,
        showEvent: 'click',
        onSelect: function onSelect(formattedDate, date, inst) {
          if (date.length >= 2) {
            $('#js-datepicker-form input#date').val(formattedDate);
            $('#js-datepicker-form').submit();
          }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Так и не понял, причём здесь URL и в чём конкретно Вы ожидаете рационализаторских предложений.

Comment: непонятна суть вопроса

Comment: Нужно получить get-параметром дату.

Comment: @ОлегНечаев у вас что в `onsubmit` идет запрос методом `get` до скрипта где происходит обработка? На самом деле вопрос непонятен, по этому вы и не получили ответа!